# Error converting VARCHAR(MAX) to XML due to "UTF-8" attribute

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, xml, cast

I need to dig into a logs table with a schema similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  data varchar(max)
);
```

Column `data` stores a XML text received from a web service in this format:

<sub>This is a reduced version</sub>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PARAM>
  <TAB DIM="30" ID="ZC3D2_1" SIZE="5">
    <LIN NUM = "1">
      <FLD NAME = "ZDOC" TYPE = "Char">Ferran López</FLD>
    </LIN>
  </TAB>
</PARAM>
```

When I try to cast this text to XML I get next error:

> XML parsing: line xx, character 48, illegal xml character

It can be solved by removing the `<xml>` tag, or at least, the `encoding` attribute.

> NOTE: It works fine if there is no special characters like `ó`, even if I don't remove `<xml>` tag.

**Question**

Is there a way to convert it to XML without replacing or removing `<xml>` tag?

```
CAST(REPLACE(data, 'encoding="UTF-8"', '') as XML)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d54d2b841db0bd4ae2a3cadd07b9e57b)*

**UPDATE**

The server collation is: **Latin1_General_BIN**

But even if I try to change the collation to my usual servers collation, it doesn't work.

```
SELECT
  id, 
  CAST((data COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS) as XML)
FROM
  t;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's happening here is:

1. The `XML` type stores data internally as UTF-16 Little Endian (most of the time, at least). It doesn't matter what the source encoding is, the end-result will be UTF-16 LE (and no `<xml>` tag, hence no `encoding="..."`).
2. When converting a string to `XML`:

   1. It's the *bytes* of the string that get converted, *not* the characters (will explain the difference in a moment)
   2. `NVARCHAR` data is assumed to be UTF-16 LE. If there is an `<xml>` tag *and* it contains the `encoding` attribute, the only valid value is `"UTF-16"`.
   3. `VARCHAR` data is assumed to be in the 8-bit code page associated with the collation of the data when there is no `<xml>` tag, or if one exists but there is no `encoding` attribute. Else the data will be *interpreted* as being encoded in the code page specified in the `encoding` attribute (even though it *is* encoded in the code page associated with the collation of the data).
3. Your data is most likely encoded as Windows code page 1252 (this is determined by the collation of the column that the data resides in, not the collation of the instance or even the database, but since you mention that the instance is using `Latin1_General_BIN`, it's safe-enough to assume for the moment that the column is using the same collation).
4. The code point for the `ó` character in code page Windows-1252 is: **0xF3**.
5. The `<xml>` tag, however, is declaring that the XML data is encoded as UTF-8.
6. In UTF-8, **0xF3** *must* be followed by three bytes, each being between **0x80** and **0xBF**, yet in your data it's followed by a `p`, which has a value of **0x70**. Hence you get the "illegal xml character" error (because the `encoding="UTF-8"` tells the conversion function that the *bytes* are valid UTF-8 bytes; the conversion doesn't see the `ó` character).

Your options are:

1. Ideally, the column would be converted to `XML` *and* the `encoding` attribute of the `<xml>` tag, or the entire `<xml>` tag itself, would be removed on the way in. AND, the `XML` datatype *can* save space if there are repeating element and/or attribute names as it creates a dictionary (lookup list) of names internally and records the structure using the ID values.
2. Set the `[data]` column to use a UTF-8 collation (new in SQL Server 2019, so not an option for you)
3. Set the `[data]` column to be `NVARCHAR`, *and* remove the `encoding` attribute of the `<xml>` tag, or the entire `<xml>` tag.
4. Convert the incoming string into UTF-8 bytes. So the `ó` character is two bytes in UTF-8: **0xC3B3**, which appear as `Ã³` in Windows-1252.

   ```sql
   DECLARE @Good VARCHAR(MAX) = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><a>hell'
           + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 0xC3B3)
           + '</a>';
   SELECT @Good, CONVERT(XML, @Good)
   -- <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><a>hellÃ³</a>
   --
   -- <a>helló</a>
   ```

**NOTES:**

- Simply removing the `encoding` attribute of the `<xml>` tag, or the entire `<xml>` tag, is *not* an option. Sure, it will work in this particular case, but it won't work in all cases due to the column being `VARCHAR` *and* UTF-8 collations not being available in SQL Server 2014. Hence, any Unicode characters not available in Windows code page 1252 will be converted to `?` or `??` (depending on BMP character or Supplementary Character):

  ```sql
  DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(MAX) = '<test>ó - ☢ - </test>';
  SELECT @Test, CONVERT(XML, @Test);
  -- <test>ó - ? - ??</test>
  --
  -- <test>ó - ? - ??</test>
  ```
- Do *NOT* simply change the collation of the column to a different locale / culture. While that might get rid of the error, it would only accomplish that by silently getting rid of the data that was causing the error. For example:

  ```sql
  DECLARE @Data NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'ó';
  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @Data COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN) AS [Latin1_General],
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @Data COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN) COLLATE
               Cyrillic_General_CI_AS AS [Cyrillic];
  /*
  Latin1_General    Cyrillic
  ó                 o
  */
  ```

  "Cyrillic" uses a different code page than "Latin1_General", and the `ó` character is not available on the Cyrillic code page. But, there is a "Best Fit" mapping which is why we end up with an `o` instead of a `?`.
- You, and anyone working on SQL Server 2008 or newer, really should be using the `_100_` level collations. Additionally, anyone working on SQL Server 2012 or newer should ideally be using the `_100_` level collation that ends with `_SC` (for Supplementary Characters). Finally, when needing a binary collation on SQL Server 2005 or newer, use one ending in `_BIN2` (see my post [here](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2019/03/13/differences-between-the-various-binary-collations-cultures-versions-and-bin-vs-bin2/) as to why).
- This issue has nothing to do with whether the query is ad hoc or in a stored procedure (T-SQL or SQLCLR).

Comment: Thanks Solomon, by now I converted the column to XML and I removed <xml> line. I'll try to encode the source, when I have more time.

Comment: @McNets You're welcome! I'm not sure what you mean about "encoding the source". If the data coming in is correct, then there's nothing more to do. And the data looked correct before. Just because the XML document stated that the encoding was UTF-8 doesn't mean that the data was UTF-8 when it was received by SQL Server. But, if you want to do a more thorough test, just pass in the characters (from the app) in the XML in the first code block in the **NOTES** section. And, I just updated to clarify a few things, so please review the [changes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/278786/revisions).

Comment: Data comes from a web service called from a C# app. I'm not sure if the server returns it correctly encoded as utf-8. I suppose the answer is yes, it is properly encoded, But I could try to use Encoding.UTF8 before to send i to SQL server.

Comment: @McNets How the data is encoded outside of SQL Server is irrelevant, so long as each step in the process understands the encoding of data coming in and going out, even if those are two different encodings. If the C# app is connecting to SQL Server via ADO.NET, then you don't need to do anything. The data within .NET (`string`, `XmlDocument`, etc) is already UTF-16, and most (all?) drivers for connecting to SQL Server via TDS use UTF-16 to transfer the data regardless of the encoding prior to hitting that connectivity code. If the app is using `XmlDocument`, it shouldn't output the `encoding`.

Answer (score 7):

Your XML stored in a varchar(max) column should look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PARAM>
  <TAB DIM="30" ID="ZC3D2_1" SIZE="5">
    <LIN NUM = "1">
      <FLD NAME = "ZDOC" TYPE = "Char">Ferran LÃ³pez</FLD>
    </LIN>
  </TAB>
</PARAM>
```

The `ó` should be represented with a double byte value `Ã³`.

If you don't have a UTF-8 encoded string stored in your column, the right way to go about this is to remove the encoding from the XML before you convert the value to the XML datatype.

Comment: The code uses a stored procedure to insert the text. Could it be encoded inside the stored procedure?

Comment: @McNets I guess with CLR but not in T-SQL. If you can't fix it on the side that calls the procedure you should remove the encoding from the XML declaration before storing the XML in the table.
You could argue that the XML sent to you as string parameter to the stored procedure is invalid XML and needs to be fixed where it is created.

Answer (score 6):

I think you have a deeper problem. UTF-8 allow for more characters than the regular non-Unicode collations in SQL server. So, to be safe you should either use SQL Server 2019 which has UTF-8 collations (and I sunderstand if that isn't doable/desirable for many reasons) os use (try) nvarchar instead of varchar.

If you are afraid of storage increase going from varchar to nvarchar, you can possibly use row compression. But that requires Enterprise Edition prior to SQL Server 2016.

Comment: The only SQL version "approved" for this ERP is 2014.

Comment: @McNets and Tibor: Row Compression (including Unicode compression) is not going to work on a MAX type. Page compression will sometimes get you some savings, but not a substantial amount. Also, `NVARCHAR` is not an option _if_ the `encoding="UTF-8"` portion of the `<xml>` tag cannot be removed as having it in there will cause an error when converting that to `XML`.

Comment: Good catch regarding the MAX type Solomon! So, since UTF-8 has a broader span of characters than a varchar allow for, the only safe way would be to removing the encoding portion and use nvarchar, as I can see...

Answer (score 4):

use a compatible collation for your varchar

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t (
>   id int PRIMARY KEY,
>   data varchar(max) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8
> );
>
> INSERT INTO t VALUES
> (1, N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <PARAM>
>   <TAB DIM="30" ID="ZC3D2_1" SIZE="5">
>     <LIN NUM = "1">
>       <FLD NAME = "ZDOC" TYPE = "Char">Ferran López</FLD>
>     </LIN>
>   </TAB>
> </PARAM>
> ')
> GO
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>   id, 
>   CAST(data as XML)
> FROM
>   t;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | (No column name)                                                                                                            
> -: | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | <PARAM><TAB DIM="30" ID="ZC3D2_1" SIZE="5"><LIN NUM="1"><FLD NAME="ZDOC" TYPE="Char">Ferran López</FLD></LIN></TAB></PARAM>
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=69e25abaf293f31af37006f7189448b1)*

Comment: It says that collation Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8 is not valid.

Comment: it  is only to show that you need the right collation.

Comment: @McNets the problems exist since vb 6 you have always to convert utf8 to unicode first, before storing it. Or switch to something more recent like 2017/2019